# SQL server Create database is failing in AWS RDS instance

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 19, Procedure rds_create_database_trigger, Line 216 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Unable to create database: Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'M*****A-N****\myt**.af****', error code 0x54b.
> Msg 3609, Level 16, State 2, Line 2

We have created a Domain login on the RDS sql instance and have given permission but it is still failing while creating database.

I'm not sure why it is failing with a trigger mentioned as this is a new instance created by me now.